# When triggering an event on an array element (with querySelectorAll) triggers an element from another array inside him (also with querySelectAll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

In the code below, when passing and removing the mouse (`mouseover` and `mouseout`) on a `li`, I would like to change only the element corresponding to that `li`, in this case, the tags `a` and `i` inside the `li`, in the same way that happens with the CSS of the code (background and color of the tag `i` changed with hover). The problem I have now is that when I trigger the event, instead of just changing the element within the `li` that the mouse is on at the moment, all elements are affected at once.

The complete code in on codepen:
http://codepen.io/RaoniSousa/pen/wJqdNP

```
function abc() {
    var liB = document.querySelectorAll('li')
        , liBArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'))
        , icons = document.querySelectorAll('li i')
        , iconsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li i'));
    //MOUSEOVER
    function changeI() {
        'use strict';
        if (iconsArray.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
                iconsArray[i].style.fontSize = '2em';
            }
        }
    }
    //MOUSEOUT
    function backI() {
        'use strict';
        if (iconsArray.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
                iconsArray[i].style.fontSize = '1em';
            }
        }
    }
    if (liBArray.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < liB.length; i++) {
            liBArray[i].addEventListener("mouseover", changeI);
            liBArray[i].addEventListener("mouseout", backI);
        }
    }
}
abc();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use javascript for what you are trying to achieve. This could be all done using css. And your javascript is working properly, it's affecting only one li at a time, but because the way you added css it's affecting design of the whole `ul` section.

Working example, without JS

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #898989;
}

#container {
    width: 1030px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none!important;
    outline: 0!important;
    border: 0!important
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0!important;
    border: 0!important
}

li {
    list-style: none
}

img {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 13em;
    background-color: #a8a8a8;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #e0e0e0
}

#footFlex {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
}

#footFlex > div:not(p){
    margin-top: 6%!important
}

#footFlex ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

#footFlex .socialLinks li a {
    border: 2px solid #fff !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s;
 font-size: 1em;
}

#footFlex .socialLinks li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
}

#footFlex li:hover i{
    color: #722872;
}

#footFlex li i:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
}

#footFlex li i{
    transition: all .5s;
    color: #fff
}

#footFlex div:first-child p:nth-child(2){
    width: 65%;
    left: 17.5%
}

#footFlex div p:nth-child(1){
    font-size: 1.3em
}

#footFlex div:first-child p:nth-child(2) a{
    color: #722872;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#footFlex div:first-child p:nth-child(2) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #722872!important
}

#footFlex div:first-child p:first-child, #footFlex div:nth-child(2) p:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 1em
}

footer + div {
    height: 5.6em;
    background-color: #722872;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    line-height: 5.6em;
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FreeCodeCamp.css">
</head>

<body id="about" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
 
    <footer>
    <div id="footFlex">
       <div>           
           <p>ABOUT THIS PAGE</p>
           <p>Made with <i class="fa fa-fw fa-music"></i> and <i class="fa fa-fw fa-coffee"></i> by <a href="">Justin Sane.</a></p>
       </div>
       <div>
           <p>AROUND THE WEB</p>
           <ul class="socialLinks">
              <li><a rel="nofollow" class="button social" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/hallaathrad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
              <li><a rel="nofollow" class="button social" href="https://github.com/hallaathrad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-github"></i></a></li>
              <li><a rel="nofollow" class="button social" href="https://twitter.com/hallaathrad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a rel="nofollow" class="button social" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/hallaathrad/" title="My Flickr"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
    <div>qlip © 2017. All Rights Reversed</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JSbin url https://jsbin.com/lahuvi/edit?html,output
It's better to use css for things like this.

Comment: I've already done this with css, but when studying js i got curious about doing this with javascript. But thanks for you tip.

Comment: Great, your JavaScript is working, but it's visually look like affecting all li, you can verify this by changing color or backgroundColor in `changeI` and `backI` function.

Comment: Yeah, affectting all li is my problem and i cannot solve this now.

Comment: Please check this, https://jsbin.com/lahuvi/edit?html,js,output I added similar feature using JavaScript, you don't need to loop over inside your invoked function, you could just use `this` to refer the item on which `mouseover` or `mouseout` event triggered on.